# Zend framework - check if view exists and not exists use another path?

Tags: zend-framework

The default view path is view/scripts while i've another view/abc/scripts so for my default system it will use the default path while abc system use the abc path.

I have layout plugin to set it from bootstrap so it will see either one of the path.

But I just noticed that for abc system I may have view exactly the same from default. I can copy the file to abc folder but then I will have duplicate file and the content is exactly the same.

So I'm wondering if there's a way I can put in some code in one place other than controller(instead of every controller or one controller while other extends it) so if the view file not exists then it will look at the default path for the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple paths in bootstrap

```
protected function _initView(){
    $view = new Zend_View();

    $view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . 'path/to/path1');
    $view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . 'path/to/path2');

    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
        'ViewRenderer'
    );
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);

    return $view;
}
```

Comment: Is this mean it will look at both path for the view script? And if any one of the path contains the file then it will use it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is simple to use file_exists function.

Comment: Do you mean using file_exists inside _initView()? But what do you put inside the file_exists? Like how do you get the file you try to render? Can you please be specific?